# Is there a common general term for "protected information"?

Tags: terminology, protection

Is there a general term for the "protected information" that you are trying to protect?

Sometimes it's code or password or token or trade secrets or proprietary information and I would like to know if there is a word for that in general.

Comment: Why not use the term "secret"? Or "sensitive information"?

Comment: @Arminius I think that it also could be proprietary work copyrighted, that is neither secret nor sensitive and just copyrighted proprietary and must not be copied even though it is neither secret nor sensitive. Practically I pay a contractor and use his work in my project and try to enforce it from being copied or extracted.

Answer (score 1):

The very general term is "[protected information](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/protected-information)". *How* it is protected will depend on the classification.

Different industries and contexts will refine what "protected information" means even further, but those definitions become technical in their niche.